# How to hide keyboard on phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

I am using 1.0 PhoneGap for android. I have an application form with several fields, one of them is to put the anniversary. I put a datepicker that field, yet when you click on the field, the keyboard appears. how can I disable the keyboard?

Code as below :

```
<label> Date: </label> <input id="datepicker" type"text" name="date"/>
```

Comment: Did you find its solution? i am stuck in this.

Answer (score 5):

You can mark the input field as read only and then create a function for an onclick event to display the datepicker.

Comment: Great thinking! Solved my problem completely.

Comment: BTW... My problem was in Phonegap/Cordova trying to stop the keyboard poping up before the datepicker (using the datepicker plugin).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what JS library you're using, but in jQuery, you'd do:

```
$('#datepicker').focus(function() {
  this.blur();
});
```

Comment: This works if the keyboard is not already visible.  If it's already shown, do you know a way to hide it?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to hide keyboard on android you can [use this plugin](https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard)

use it like that:

```js
plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide(function () {
    // success
},function () {
   // fail
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use the new HTML5 input types.

```
<input type="date" name="bday" />
```

in Google Chrome i get the following:

[image: 'Date' HTML5 input type]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and saved my head from excessive scratching!

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```

The solution was found [here](http://uihacker.blogspot.cz/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html), where you can find a non `jQuery` solution.