# phonegap android GO button to not submit form

Tags: android, forms, cordova, button, submit

I'm writing an app with Phonegap and I have a register form that is sent through ajax. 
 It works fine when you hit the register button and execute the `formcheck()` function. However, when I hit the `GO` button from my android phone it submits the form instead of going through the `formcheck()` process. I tried:

```
<form id="RegForm" onsubmit="formcheck();return false;">
```

My form has no proper submit button but a button like this:

```
<input type="button" id="submitbtn" onclick="formcheck()"/>
```

I also tried to create a `new OnSubmitForm()` function that calls the `formcheck()` one but with no avail. 
 Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

1) Add this to the JS section:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#YourFormName").submit(function() {
    FormCheck();
    return false;
    });
});

function FormCheck() {
... validation process here ...
}
```

2) Make sure to include a Submit button in your form .. ( `<input type="submit"` )

Hope it'll help others so my 5 hour trying & testing time won't go wasted :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply ensure your form tag is:

```
<form type='submit' onsubmit='return false;'></form>
```

This makes the submit action not do anything.

If you also need to hide the keyboard refer to [How can I hide the Android keyboard using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript). A simple onsubmit='hideKeyboard(); return false;' will take care of this.