# Stop form submitting when clicking 'Go' on mobiles

Tags: javascript, html, .net, forms, mobile

Is there a way to link a button to an input, so mobiles know what to do when you press `Next` or `Go` on the keyboard within a .NET context (i.e. Pressing 'Go' on an input fakes the click on the next button instead of submitting the form)?

Let's talk code for a second. I have the following markup, where `injected-via-js` is injected via javascript into a large form (progressive enhancement).

```
<form class="dotNET-form-wrapper">
    <div class="injected-via-js">
        <div>
            <span>&pound;</span>
            <input type="number" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>accept</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- More form elements -->
</form>
```

On most mobile browsers, when you change the value in the number input and press `Go` or `Enter` it fakes the button press (which in my case has an important event bound to it). However on some old Android devices pressing `Go` will submit the form instead, which is **not** what I want. To clarify: **I want the `Go` button to fake the button press, not submit the form**.

**Note:**
.NET is only relevant to this question due to the fact that **everything** is wrapped in a form, meaning I cannot create a separate form around the input and button and highjack the new form's submit.

I've made a JSBin where I was able to replicate this bug with an `Android 2.2` phone although I imagine it exists on other bad browsers as well. It works as expected on `iOS 6+` and `Android 2.3+`.

Here's the demo page: http://jsbin.com/tebizoda/2

And here's the edit version: http://jsbin.com/tebizoda/2/edit

Comment: what mobile platforms?

Comment: I've seen this bug on a HTC Desire running Android 2.2 on their default browser. I imagine other platforms with similar versions of Android + rubbish browsers also have this issue. I'm ideally trying to find a solution that negates the need for the browser to 'guess' what to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177847/phonegap-android-go-button-to-not-submit-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both "Go" and "Enter" has keycodes like the enter on the keyboard (13) so you should just make a JavaScript or jQuery function that overrides the default behaviour and just triggers the button press. Something like (example in jQuery):

```
$(your_form_or_input).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    return false;
  } else {
    // your code here...
  }
});
```

Mind that some browsers use e.keyCode, others e.which to determine the pressed key code.

Comment: Awesome. Seemed to have done the trick. Instead of returning false when enter was pressed, I just triggered the click event on the button.