# trigger.io - close soft keyboard?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, trigger.io

Is there a way to programatically close the Android on screen keyboard with trigger.io?

I have a search field with an auto-complete search on. When the user stops typing I show the search results, but the onscreen keyboard stays visible - obscuring a number of the results.

Comment: Even though I provided a solution below, I'm not sure whether it would be *good* user experience to hide the keyboard when the user *stops typing*. How do you define this (e.g. when the user doesn't type for x seconds)? Showing / hiding the keyboard can take some time and you should be sure the user is not going to type something afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

There are actually two ways of doing this using `Trigger.io`:

**Native plugin**

You can write a [native plugin](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html) that hides the soft keyboard. The relevant code should look something like this (based on [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)):

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) ForgeApp.getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ForgeApp.getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

---

**Javascript**

The proper way to hide the soft keyboard using Javascript would be to blur the element that is currently focused. In modern browsers, you just need to call:

```
document.activeElement.blur()
```

However, `document.activeElement` is not always available and sometimes seems to be incorrect. I use something like this:

```
if (document.activeElement && 
    document.activeElement.blur && 
    document.activeElement !== document.body) {
  document.activeElement.blur();
}
else {
  jQuery(':focus').blur();
}
```

Even this will not work for **some** Android 2.x devices. Check out [How can I hide the Android keyboard using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript) for more workarounds.

Comment: I needed a JS solution. Working beautifully when called after enter key.