# How to remove keyboard when there is no focus in input field in android mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application I have three input fields. If I click on first input field and I did not write any validate data, and then I go to second input field -- it is showing a popup because of validation for change event. Here in this the keyboard that appeared when we click on the first input field is not removed when the popup showed up.

For this I removed the `.focus` for input field and

I tried like this also:

```
$('input').blur();
```

But there is no use I don't understand what is the exact problem it comes in Celkon device. Please suggest me any appropriate solution for this issue.

Comment: Can you check in your device with `setTimeout`? setTimeout(function(){
 $('input').blur();
}, 1000);

Comment: I put that one in mycode but it is not working. The keyboard is showing .

Comment: This is a duplicate question. It is questioned and answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript