# Is there any way to hide keyboard in Android 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I don't know that's possible or not, my question is : Is there anyway to hide keyboard in Android 4.0.4 using jQuery or Javascript?

Because I developed application that using mobile device Android.

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input"/>
```

As we know, when We focus to textbox, soft keyboard will appear.

Any advice ? Please help.

Comment: you can do this in native by `InputType.TYPE_NULL` something like `input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`

Comment: @Ashok in example please :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Android Code programatically like `fromInput` is an `EditText` if you put the following code in `onCreate()` method, keyboard will not appear on `EditText`

```
private EditText fromInput
fromInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fromInput);
fromInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Consider the following [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript) for hiding the keyboard using ***javscript***

Comment: I using web base programming.

Comment: have a glance on the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the soft-keyboard won't popup for the myEditText.

```
myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fromInput);    
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);    
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really dont want to show keyboard on focus of textox, Simply use a DIV and using css give it a style so it looks like textbox.
OR
mark it as readonly if u dont want user to edit it. readonly="true"