# How to hide Keyboard from inside Android's Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

Inside Android's webview, a from containing a textarea is processed by javascript.
The problem: After submitting/processing the form, the Keyboard does not disappear, unless the user clicks outside.

I would like to make the keyboard disappear, right after form submission. How can this be achieved?

```
<form>
    <textarea>Hi there...</textarea>
</form>

<script>
   $("form").submit(function(){
      processForm();

      // I tried .blur() and .focusout(), which make the textarea loose focus, 
      // but the keyboard still does not hide...
      // $("textarea").blur();
      // $("textare").focusout();

      return false;       
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Have your checked this SO question:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript?

Comment: I really searched, but didn't find this one. Will check it out... Thanks!

Comment: Just tried all of the linked approaches, but none of them worked...

Comment: Have you tried JavaScriptInterface solution calling Java code from the last answer at the link I provided to you?

Comment: Check the possibilities in the link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548564/6584867

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").reset();
```

Resetting the form should cause the keyboard to hide.  Alternatively, you could try.

```
$('input').blur();
```