# How to hide keyboard when user clicks on textbox in webview android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

Can we hide android system keyboard when user focuses or clicks on html input elements inside the webview.

I have tried hiding keyboard on user touches webview:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
        Toast.makeText(cx,"Web View Touch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
            return true;
    }
})
```

But that doesn't work.

Is there option to hide keyboard entirely for a app?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29409478/5312278

Comment: Thanks @riazhasan I have just tried that. When I clicks on textarea in webview it is not working.

Comment: Hey sorry it is working in emulator Nexus4 API 19. But while I am checking with Moto G through USB it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the [softkeyboard - Handling Input Method Visibility](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) for each activity with the manifest like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >

<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
```

You can also control it so it flows using 'next' from one edittext to the next and then hides again with 'done' using [IME options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions).

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

I also realise the problem would be with using a webview and needing to also disable any keyboard from parent layouts,as the webview is separate from the activities in the manifest, so add this to any parent layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and in the webview:

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Hey it is working in emulator Nexus4 API 19. But while I am checking with Moto G through USB it is not working. Any idea regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this in the activity in manifest.xml..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

it may help.