# .innerHTML breaks layout of jQuery mobile split ListView sample

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

likely more of a beginner type question but. If I use the following code on a page it works fine, and displays what I need ( Listview from jquery )

```
<ul data-role="listview"  data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="alarmcritical.png" width=25px;>
        <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
        <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
    </li>
<br>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="alarmminor.png" width=25px;>
            <h2>Warning</h2>
            <p>Hot Chip</p>
        </a>
    </li>
<br>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="alarmmajor.png" width=25px;>
    <h2>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>
    <p>Phoenix</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I am updating one section of a page by using

```
document.getElementById('insertHere').innerHTML = stringData;
```

stringData being one long line of the html above...and I've copy pasted that as one line to ensure it does work ( outside of the innerhtml ).

So I have a span for inserthere, and was hoping to have the same effect as if I just typed the html out itself. But everytime it comes out broken ( not formatted as a listview ). Is this a common problem, or am I overlooking something?

Thanks

Edit: Updating with Javascript - Be gentle, rather new to it and am using a lot of example source code

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {

   //check array for company name that was entered
    for(var i = 0; i < cases.length;i++){
    if(ui.item.value == cases[i].companyName)
    index = cases[i].id;
    }
    var company = "";

    //set the company name to match the one the customer selected
    company = cases[index].companyName;

    //display on page the cases for the customer selected

    var stringData = '<ul data-role="listview"  data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true"><li><a     href="#">    <img src="alarmcritical.png" width=25px;>    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>    <p>Broken Bells</p></a></li><br><li><a href="#">    <img src="alarmminor.png" width=25px;>    <h2>Warning</h2>    <p>Hot Chip</p></a></li><br><li><a href="#">    <img src="alarmmajor.png" width=25px;>    <h2>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>    <p>Phoenix</p></a></li>';

    document.getElementById('insertHere').innerHTML = stringData;

    //hide keyboard after user is done selecting
    //source code found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript
    hideKeyboard($('input'));
      function hideKeyboard(element) {
            element.attr('readonly', 'readonly'); // Force keyboard to hide on input field.
            element.attr('disabled', 'true'); // Force keyboard to hide on textarea field.
            setTimeout(function() {
                element.blur();  //actually close the keyboard
                // Remove readonly attribute after keyboard is hidden.
                element.removeAttr('readonly');
                element.removeAttr('disabled');
                }, 100);
        }


    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
      var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
      result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );


      //set a brief timeout between the actual click of the case and when it displays
      setTimeout(func, 500);
      //display the case details
        function func() {
        document.getElementById('insertHere').innerHTML = '<div class="shadow"><table  id=\"selectable\" border:0.5px BORDERCOLOR=black><tr><td height=10%><h2>' + company + '</h2></td></tr><table  id=\"selectable\" border:0.5px BORDERCOLOR=black><tr><td><img src=ic_priority.png>Priority Status</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<td><img src=ic_escalation.png>Escalation</td></tr></table><br><table id=\"selectable\" border:0.5px BORDERCOLOR=black><tr><td><img src=\"ic_agent.png\" valign=bottom>&nbsp<button data-theme="a"><img src=ic_action_call.png></button><button><img src=\"ic_action_chat.png\"></button</td></tr><tr><td>Case: ' + customerCases[index].caseNumber + ' </td></tr><tr><td>Status: Open</td></tr><tr><td>Updated: 8 May 2014 15:09:46</td></tr><tr><td>Contact: Bob Kingston</td></tr><td>Agent: ' + customerCases[index].contactName + '</td><tr><td>State: Offline</td></tr><tr><td><br></td></tr><tr><td>Issue:</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + customerCases[index].problem  + '</td></tr></table></div>';
        }
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

});

$("input[name=companyName]").autocomplete({
       source: cases
   }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("

").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("" + item.url + "").appendTo(ul);
    };

```
//$('div').addClass('shadow');

</script>
```

All the above is in the head.
What I'm doing is having a autocomplete bring up some information from a local array. So when you first search it brings up something, then after you select one it brings up a page with the selected information. All going into "inserthere". But I cannot seem to get it to work properly when I use the innerHTML with the stringData I wrote.

Comment: I don't think it would affect anything in your case, but your above markup is invalid. The only legitimate child of a `<ul>` element is an `<li>` element. The `<br>` tags are invalid as currently written...

Answer (score 0):

Your manipulating the DOM after page has been rendered and the listview has been applied prior to your manipulation. You'll need to reapply the listview to the list after manipulating it with your javascript. Here's a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubergoober/YN8Gm/) showing that process. If you append items (or insert or prepend) you can just do a .listview("refresh") since the listview has been rendered already. Only when you replace the whole `ul` or `ol` (which had the listview bound to it) do you need to reapply. Replacing that whole `ul` is precisely what you're doing in your example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stringData = '<ul id="listToShow" data-role="listview"  data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true"><li><a     href="#">    <img src="alarmcritical.png" width=25px;>    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>    <p>Broken Bells</p></a></li><br><li><a href="#">    <img src="alarmminor.png" width=25px;>    <h2>Warning</h2>    <p>Hot Chip</p></a></li><br><li><a href="#">    <img src="alarmmajor.png" width=25px;>    <h2>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>    <p>Phoenix</p></a></li>';

    $('#insertHere').html(stringData);

    $('#listToShow').listview();
});
```

**Note:** I added an id to the `ul` so that we can reference it when reapplying the listview to it.

Comment: I don't believe War10ck's comment on your OP about the `<br>` tags is accurate. It's not that they are invalid, but unnecessary (most of the times). `li` tags will automatically break to a new line unless you specify otherwise (say via CSS). As is, they will just add another break between list items (in your case). For example, this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubergoober/YN8Gm/3/) has several more `br` tags added which create a bigger gap between a couple of the list items.

Comment: The JSFiddle above shows how I don't want it to look ( unless I'm missing some kind of library to link it to with jsfiddle). As an example, here is how it looks if I put it right in the html

http://s12.postimg.org/ytpa54x5p/in_HTML.png

and here is how it looks if I load it within my JS

http://s28.postimg.org/at05yxf0t/in_JS.png

I should mention that this is appearing after a autocomplete ( from a jquery example ). I will update the first post with the full javascript.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood what was going on. Answer has been updated with working example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had jquery ui as well as jquery mobile in my imports, they do not seem to play well together as when I take out the jquery ui css, I can show it with the .innerHTML.

I'll have to use a jquery mobile autocomplete, as the one I was using required the ui.