# Is there a way to block the soft keyboard when an input get focus on phonegap?

Tags: cordova, soft-keyboard

Is there a way to block the soft keyboard when an input get foucs, but DO NOT 
lose the input's focus (keep the cursor in the input filed)?

I'm programming a phonegap application on android. I have to show a custom keyboard, 
which is not an IME, just is an android activity, paint as a soft keyboard(for some 
reason, I can change this solution). The problem is that when the input get focus, the custom 
keyboard and system's soft keyboard(IME) both are displayed. Can I block the system's soft 
keyboard ?

Hum, it's a phonegap application and the input is a HTML input and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar situation myself on a current cordova/backbone app we're working on.

### Our situation:

We had datepicker / timepicker plugins we were using with JQuery. These plugins provided their own interface for selecting and inputting time/date values. However whenever an input field for a date or time picker gained focus the soft-keyboard would be revealed. This was confusing, as the user is expected to input data via the onscreen calendar/time dial and not the softkeyboard.

### Solution

Our solution for this was to add the `readonly` attribute to our `<input>`'s. Since we were setting these values programmatically, there was no reason to make these inputs read/write fields. From our experience it seems that setting a field to `readonly` will prevent the soft keyboard from showing up when those input fields receive focus

Answer (score 0):

In `config.xml` add the following preferences:

```
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateHidden"/>
```

other examples here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                             "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                             "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                             "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                             "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >
```

**In answer to op's comment:**

See this:
[How can I hide the Android keyboard using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript)

Comment: It doesn't work on my problem. I mean that how to block soft keyboard when the input get focus. The android:windowSoftInputMode is for 'The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention'.

Comment: Forgive me, but that sounds like exactly what you are after... maybe you can explain the issue in more depth?

Comment: I try to describe it more clear: When a HTML input element gets 
a focus(whatever touch on the input or call input.focus()), then
a soft keyboard will be bring out. This is the OS's default behavior,
right? And I attempt to prevent this default behavior. I hope this 
soft keyboard is hidden, and the input still get the focus(the cursor
is still in the input field). How can I do it?

The attribute of 'android:windowSoftInputMode' is not work. It seems to
set the soft-keyboard's state at the moment of the application is opened
but user touches the input.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem I need to Prevent the Keyboard from showing on focus / click in the field it should only show when I call show() or hide() from the ionic keyboard plugin