# WYSIWYG editor misbehaves when editing in android webview

Tags: android, webview, wysiwyg

I am creating an android application which uses webview to show a static html page which contains **TinyMCE editor**. When i click on editing area of editor for editing purpose, softkey keyboard opens and whatever text is written in text area gets cleared. In addition to this when i select text(by long click on text) for changing its style, and when i click on any of toolbar button(i.e. Bold, Italic, Underline etc), again text get cleared. This problem is not only with my app but also with default browser of android(although works perfect with **Dolphin browser**).

Device for which application is developed is a android-TV device(A75). This behavior is with this device particularly. The same behaviour is with some other **WYSIWYG** editors like **CKeditor,** **nicEditor,** **bootstrap-wysihtml5** also.

What i have tried so far is, to hide softkeyboard when editor is clicked for ediging purpose, from code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160055/2530623). Although i was able to hide softkeyboard from given code but, in that case i was not able to edit and select text for formatting.

Please help me to solve this prblem.

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: The native Android WebView is very very buggy from this point of view, so you will have a lot of problems with html-based text editors (do some research on that and you will find a lot of information). This is why from Android 4.4+ the WebView has been replaced with the Chromium view, so if you use Android KK or L you will have no problems.