# Prevent Mobile Keyboard without "readonly" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, focus

How do I prevent the virtual keyboard from appearing on a mobile device when I focus an input? Something like a "onbeforefocus" event would be nice but I haven't found anything.

Since I need the ability to paste into the field I cannot set the "readonly" attribute to true (at least not permanently). Simply removing the "readonly" attribute on focus and adding it back on blur is also problematic since the next input button on mobile will skip readonly fields.

Comment: Look here for few solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript