# While reading Barcode from scanner, code needs to hide keyboard on Text Field

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, keyboard

I am trying to have focus on input element using

```
$('#barcodeScanner').focus();
```

where `barcodeScanner` is a input textbox, but it opens up keyboard to enter input. I am trying to hide the keyboard using

```
    Keyboard.hide();
```

It's not working in the code. Can anyone help me hide the keyboard any other way?

Comment: By the tag it looks you are using cordova to buld the app and the question is specific to android app ! Am I correct ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide the Android keyboard using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you using the ionic-plugin-keyboard ?

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to lose focus on the textbox

Comment: Have you tried - cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close(); ?

Comment: @Vr1010101 - Could you please mention if it worked ?

Comment: @AbhinavArora Nope it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because you have focused on a text field, by default text field will open the keyboard. You can handle it in several ways.

First don't focus on a text input and focus on a div or any other element, and there should be a event on that div or that other element, when CHAR(13) or carriage return is read from the barcode it should put it that value in a hidden input to submit the form. I am guess that you already know how form works.

2nd way, make the text disabled and do the same process as first one it should work , this case you don't need hidden input.

3rd way, you can also hide the text input with display:none which should also fix the problem.

4th, do a blur after the focus and handle the scenario.

Let me know if any works.