# Javascript: hide soft keyboard in mo

Tags: javascript

how to hide keyBoard if textfield tap in mobile

using javascript

i have in trouble for resolve it

i just use this line to avoid keyboard

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideAndroidKeyboard() {
    Android.hideKeyboard();
}
</script>
```

but i want to hide keyboard from all devices

Answer (score 1):

just blur the focus  on screen by using this

```
$(document.activeElement).filter(':input:focus').blur();
```

for better assistance: [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript)