# php, android: bluetooth scanner disables software keyboard

Tags: php, android, bluetooth, keyboard, barcode-scanner

While writing a **cakePHP** mobile application that lets me scan products and store them in my db, I keep running into a certain issue when using a **bluetooth scanner** on an **Android** mobile device:

As long as the scanner is on (or connected via bluetooth) the **on-screen keyboard** of the phone cannot be used, it just doesn't appear when you tap any input field.

I've found various threads on this topic, for example this one:
https://community.wyse.com/forum/showthread.php?6450-No-keyboard-when-paired-with-Bluetooth-bar-code-scanner&p=70424

It seems like (most of the time) this problem can be solved by OS settings but I was wondering: Is there a way to **tell the device or browser via php to open the software keyboard?** Any other possible solutions, maybe using JavaScript or something similar?
Does it depend on the browser too?

Thanks in advance, any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: corrected name of object

Answer (score 0):

i can't comment because of my reputation.. But maybe this give an idea.

[Close-Hide soft keyboard with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948607/close-hide-android-soft-keyboard-in-firefox?lq=1)

[Close-Hide soft keyboard with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045889/how-to-hide-keyboard-on-phonegap-android?lq=1)

[Close-Hide soft keyboard with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript)